# Attempting to find private key for ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When creating my EC2 instance on aws, I indicated that I wanted to setup ssh. I was ask for a user name and a password. In return, I was given an SHA256 key and the key's art. No idea what either of these are or how these can be used right now, but I have them saved.

I now want to connect to my instance via ssh, but I need a .pem or .ppk file for the private key. I have neither and have no idea where to find these or how to create them.

When I created my instance via awsebcli, would the private key have been saved somewhere on my computer?

Thanks!

Comment: `awsebcli` this is for AWS Elastic Beanstalk (EB). Can you confirm that you are talking about how to ssh into EB instances?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `eb init` you are promped for a number of things. One of them is the ssh key. For example:

```
Type a keypair name.
(Default is aws-eb): 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/xxxxx/.ssh/aws-eb
Your public key has been saved in /home/xxxx/.ssh/aws-eb.pub
```

Assuming you used default values, your key pair is called

```
aws-eb
```

Also by default, the `aws-eb` keys are stored in:

```
/home/xxxx/.ssh
```

Thus, to login to your EB instance you can do the following:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-eb ec2-user@<ip-of-the-eb-instance>
```

**Shortcut** using [eb ssh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-ssh.html)

```
eb ssh <your-eb-environment-name>
```

Comment: Yes, all i had to do was run the eb ssh shortcut you mentioned. had no idea it was that easy!

Comment: @JasonHoward the `eb ssh` basicly a wrapper around the `ssh -i ~/.ssh/aws-eb ec2-user@<ip-of-the-eb-instance>`. But it saves time on looking up the IP of the instance :-)